Active MQ messages for clean cache in Tridion 10
We are migrating from Tridion 9.5 to 10.
In our WebApp we have Akamai CDN and a Redis cache for content.
In 9.5 we developed a CacheCleaner tool that is connected to the Deployer ActiveMQ to read publication messages and then invalidating it in Akamai and our Redis Cache.
For that, we use this configuration in the deployer (cd_storage_conf.xml):
   <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
        <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
            <Param Name="MemSize" Value="1024mb"/>
        </Policy>
        <Features>
            <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
        </Features>

        <RemoteSynchronization FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="20000" Queuesize="1024" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000">
            <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Tridion">
                <JndiContext>
                    <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                    <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="ssl://b-764628ea-1e15-4385-af6e-********-1.mq.eu-*-1.amazonaws.com:61617?soTimeout=5000"/>
                    <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="Live9"/>
                    <Property Name="userName" Value="*****"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="********"/>
                    <Property Name="trustAllPackages" Value="true"/>
                </JndiContext>
            </Connector>
        </RemoteSynchronization>
    </ObjectCache>

Then, when publications finishes correctly, a message is sent to Active MQ and we can read it from our CacheCleaner App to invalidate Akamai and our Redis Cache.
But now, in Tridion 10 I can’t find this configuration.
We see that there is a JMS and active MQ configuration in the deployer-conf.xml file but it seems that is used for another proposes.
How could I configure this kind of messages to invalidate cache? Do you have any kind of configuration? I can’t find it on docs.sdl.com.

Tridion Sites 10 introduced a new caching mechanism using Apache Ignite, replacing the old implementation that used the Cache Channel Service and/or Java Messaging Service (JMS). ActiveMQ is now used primarily for deployer queues rather than cache invalidation.
To achieve cache invalidation similar to your previous setup, you can develop a custom Deployer extension that implements the ExecutableStep interface. This extension will handle the published pages' transaction details and trigger cache invalidation for Akamai and your Redis cache.
